# What are the different sanskrit exams like tritiya, bhartiya and vidya bhawan?

Tags: exams, sanskrit

I have studied sanskrit till 10th class.
I am right now in my final year of graduation pursuing dentistry.

I again want to get in touch with sanskrit language.
Hence I am planning to appear for certain exams like tritiya, bhartiya vidya bhawan etc. [Exams](https://www.ggss.org.in/Examinations-Exams%20we%20coach%20for.html)

However I searched on the net and there are lots of exams of different levels and that too in different different websites.

I am now confused as to which exam should I appear for?
What all benefits can I prevail by those?
If anyone can kindly throw some light giving me information on what all exams are good and difference between these.

## Motivation

I just want to remain in touch with the language. My main goal is dentistry only, but I want to do some extra learning on the side. And for that matter, by taking those exams I will study for them in my free time, and those exams will give a kind of degree also (not sure) plus a certificate. If I want to go out of India those certificates will benefit for the admission to some colleges which have a criteria on extra curricular activities also.